# Make several configuration saves/loadings of rpivottable on R

Tags: javascript, r, rpivottable

The following code I found on an other post (I could link if anybody is interested) adds the saving option on the R rpivottable using flexdashboard. The saving is done through cookies.
I am trying to recreate it but having multiple saving options, basically have SAVE1, SAVE2,.. and being able to load the wanted save. I am unexperienced with JS so it is really hard to do anything.

```
---
title: "rpivottable_test"
output: html_document
---
```

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

```
# devtools::install_github("fraupflaume/rpivotTable")
library(rpivotTable)
data(mtcars)
names(mtcars)[10] <- "George.Dontas"
```

Save Current Configuration
Restore Previous Configuration

```
rpivotTable(mtcars,rows="George.Dontas", cols = c("cyl"), width = "90%", height = "40%",
            rendererOptions = list(
              c3 = list(legend = list(show = FALSE), 
                        data = list(labels = TRUE),
                        options = list(responsive = TRUE,
                                       maintainAspectRatio = FALSE),
                        size = list(width = "600",
                                    height = "500")),
              d3 = list(size = list(width = "500", height = "500"))))
```

```
// save current state of the tables to my browser
setTimeout(function(){       //add the events first
  document.querySelector('a#saveBtn').addEventListener('click', savoring);
  document.querySelector('a#restoBtn').addEventListener('click', giveItBack);
  function savoring() {                             // function to save
    el = document.querySelectorAll('.rpivotTable');
    for(i=0; i < el.length; i++){
      elId = el[i].getAttribute("id");
      stringy = $('#' + elId).data("pivotUIOptions"); // collect rows/columns filters
      delete stringy['aggregators'];                 // remove the arbitrary
      delete stringy['renderers'];
      stringy2 = JSON.stringify(stringy);            // make it one key:value
      window.localStorage.setItem('table' + i, stringy2); // store it!
    }
  };
  function giveItBack() {                           // function to regurgitate
    el = document.querySelectorAll('.rpivotTable');
    console.log("working on the giver");
    ods = [...el[0].ownerDocument.scripts];         // make it an array
    for(j=0; j < el.length; j++){
      elId = el[j].getAttribute("id");
      where = ods.filter(function(ods){             // filter scripts for table data
        return ods.dataset['for'] === elId;
      })[0].innerHTML; 
      where2 = JSON.parse(where).x.data;            // WOOO HOO! I figured it out!!
      where3 = HTMLWidgets.dataframeToD3(where2);   // finally sheesh!!
      gimme = window.localStorage.getItem('table' + j); // get storage
      $('#' + elId).pivotUI(where3, JSON.parse(gimme), true, "en"); // put it back!
    }
  }
},100);
```

Comment: If there are several tables in the same dashboard or other RMD, this will save all of them at the same time. (I wrote it.) If you wanted each table to have separate save functionality, that would be a lot more work. You'll have to include more details on what exactly you're looking for. What's in your YAML?

Comment: Thank you very much for your code, Kat! It saved me multiple hours (if not days). 
I only have one table on my dashboard. 
What exactly I am looking for is having a second option listed to the saving option, that lets you choose a checkpoint, so you can reset back to the specific checkpoint you wish.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand—you want to be able to save many different configurations of the same table. That's where the SAVE1, SAVE2, etc. came from; they're the names of different saved configurations of the same table? I'll start putting something together assuming that's what you want.  (Unless you tell me otherwise.)

Comment: That is precisely what I want. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses the default system alert and prompt boxes. These vary in appearance a bit from one OS to another.

I've included CSS for the buttons and RMD. I used `html_document`. If you use `flex_dashboard` you won't need the CSS for the class `main-container`. The CSS for `body` may or may not be useful (depending on what else you have going on).

If you're using the Cran package, the `rendererOptions` won't work as-is. You have to remove a list level after you make the object. The D3 rendererOptions won't work unless you change the Javascript file, d3_renderers.js, in the `rpivotTable` package. (That's what I did with my fork.) If you use my fork, it will work as-is.

I've added handlers for

- naming violations (whitespace, special characters, that sort of thing)
- no matching name when restoring the configuration

  - returns a list of all names in storage
  - then prompts the user for another configuration name
- if cancel is pressed from prompt, it cancels the save or restore process

You may notice quite a few changes in the restoration function. That's because the original code would lost `subtotals`, `sorters`, and the `renderer` `tsv`.

I tried to think of anything that could go wrong and this is where I'm at. If you run into any issues, let me know. If you have questions, ask.

The YAML, options, and CSS:

````
---
title: "button and input tester!"
author: "me"
date: '2022-05-12'
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

<style>
body {    /*push content away from far right and left edges*/
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-left: 2%;
}
.main-container {
  max-width: unset;
}
.btn { 
  vertical-align: middle;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #000000;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #000000;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: .5px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.2em;           
  padding: .3em 0px;
  width: 20em;                 
  text-decoration: none; /*no underline!!*/
  cursor: pointer;
}
.btn:active {      /*simulate movement*/
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}
</style>
````

The table.

````
```{r data,include=F}
# devtools::install_github("fraupflaume/rpivotTable")
library(rpivotTable)
data(mtcars)

```

## Make it Interesting...or not

Do you want to save or restore the previously saved pivot tables' configuration?

<a id='saveNamed' class='btn' style="background-color:#003b70;color:white;">Save Configuration by Name</a>
<a id='restoNamed' class='btn' style="background-color:#b21e29;color:white;">Restore Configuration with Custom Name</a>


```{r showMe, echo=FALSE, fig.show="hold"}
rpivotTable(mtcars, rows="am", cols = c("cyl"), width = "90%", 
            height = "40%", subtotals = TRUE,
            rendererOptions = list(
              c3 = list(legend = list(show = FALSE), 
                        data = list(labels = TRUE),
                        options = list(responsive = TRUE,
                                       maintainAspectRatio = FALSE),
                        size = list(width = "600",
                                    height = "500")),
              d3 = list(size = list(width = "500", height = "500")) 
            ))
```


That's all, folks.
````

Lastly, the JS.

````
```{r listenOrElse,results="asis",engine="js"}

// for ONE TABLE
setTimeout(function(){  // add to buttons
  document.querySelector('a#saveNamed').addEventListener('click', savoring); 
  document.querySelector('a#restoNamed').addEventListener('click', giveItBack);
  function savoring() {                              // function to save
    el = document.querySelector('.rpivotTable');
    msg = "Choose a name for the configuration that you are saving.";
    inName = prompt(msg, ['Enter a name with no spaces or special characters'])
    if(inName === null) {return;};                   // they changed their mind; nothing saved
    inName = inName.replace(/[^a-z0-9.]/gi, '');     // validate string
    path = window.location.pathname.split("/").pop().split(".").slice()[0]; //filename
    elId = el.getAttribute("id");
    stringy = $('#' + elId).data("pivotUIOptions");  // collect rows/col filters
    delete stringy['aggregators'];                   // remove not-parse-friendly keys
    delete stringy['renderers'];
    stringy2 = JSON.stringify(stringy);              // one key:value pair for storage
    window.localStorage.setItem(path + '_' + inName, stringy2);  // STORE it!
  };
  function giveItBack() {                           // function to regurgitate
    el = document.querySelector('.rpivotTable');
    msg = "Enter the name of the configuration you would like to retrieve.";
    confName = prompt(msg, ["Enter a name with no spaces or special characters"]);
    if(confName === null) {return;}; 
    confName = confName.replace(/[^a-z0-9.]/gi, '');    // validate string
    ods = [...el.ownerDocument.scripts];             // make it an array
    path = window.location.pathname.split("/").pop().split(".").slice()[0]; //filename
    elId = el.getAttribute("id");
    where = ods.filter(function(ods){             // filter scripts for data
      return ods.dataset['for'] === elId;
    })[0].innerHTML; 
    where2 = JSON.parse(where).x.data;            // format data for pivotUI()
    where3 = HTMLWidgets.dataframeToD3(where2);   // ...still formatting
    if(window.localStorage.getItem(path + '_' + confName) === null) { // alert
      len = window.localStorage.length
      var str;
      for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        w = window.localStorage.key(i);
        ind = w.lastIndexOf('_');
        w2 = w.substr(ind + 1);   // remove file/page name and table number
        str = str + w2 + '\n';    // make one long string of names
      }
      str2 = "WARNING: There is no saved pivot table configuration with the name " + confName + '.';
      str2 += " Here is a list of the configuration names that are currently stored for this page:\n";
      str2 += str;
      alert(str2);
      confName = prompt(msg, ["Enter a name with no spaces or special characters"]);
      if(confName === null) {
        return
      }; 
      confName = confName.replace(/[^a-z0-9.]/gi, '');    // validate string
    }
    gimme = window.localStorage.getItem(path + '_' + confName); // get storage
    gimmeMore = JSON.parse(gimme);                            // prepare for recall
    if(where.includes('"subtotals":true')){       // is the option 'subtotal' used?
      gimmeMore.renderers = $.pivotUtilities.subtotal_renderers;
      gimmeMore.dataClass = $.pivotUtilities.SubtotalPivotData;
    }; 
    if(where.includes('"tsv":true')){             // is the option 'tsv' used?
      gimmeMore.renderers = $.extend(gimmeMore.renderers, $.pivotUtilities.export_renderers);
    };
    if(where.includes('sortAs')){
      // passed as a function, they will get lost in save & retrieve
      stringy = $('#' + elId).data("pivotUIOptions").sorters;
      gimmeMore.sorters = stringy;
    }
    $('#' + elId).pivotUI(where3, gimmeMore, true, "en"); // put it back!
  };
}, 500);

```
````

#### In this image, you can see that 'bar chart' was entered (name violation).

[image]

#### During restoration, I searched for 'bar' (which didn't exist).

[image]

[image]

[image]

#### Now when I'm prompted again, I'm going to type bar chart (with the space) even though you can see that 'barchart' exists, not bar chart.

[image]

#### You'll still get the chart. The handler will remove white space and special characters here, as well.

[image]

Comment: Congratulations! At a quick glance, I have two initial remarks to make. a) this is strictly for pages with a single table, right? b) I guess you could use a radiobutton list with the stored names and let the user select the desired one. Wouldn't it be easier like that?

Comment: You could; that might be easier... depends on how many versions you save! I made it for one table because that was something specifically requested. This could be done with many; this could be done with a custom dialogue box, as well. You're thinking...what's going on in that head of yours? Another idea?

Comment: Νο no, do not worry  :-)  
I was just thinking about how I would do it, while you were working.

Comment: Dear Kat, could you please elaborate on how do you so CASUALLY solve a problem I've been working on for HOURS.
I just have one remark I would like to add; do you think it is possible to implement a radiobutton (Ex-> https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/apps/design/controls/images/controls/radio-button.png) to the code? Or would it need to change the entire format?

Comment: Radio button, as in what @George Dontas mentioned? One for each stored configuration? If not, can you clarify what the buttons are for? As far as starting over? Not likely! Lastly, if there is anything you'd like me to explain in the code, let me know.

Comment: A radio button as in, a box you could open, that would display the saving checkpoints you have made. In this instance, the box would display (upon clicking on it) "bar chart"; so that it would be easier to get back to one specific checkpoints you have made. 
Lastly, your code is crystal clear, especially with the side notes, you are amazing, Kat!

Comment: While I'm adding this, do you want it limited? For example, the last 10 saves?

Comment: If there is a large difference in the coding of the 2 options (limited unlimited) then I would choose limited; whereas if it's pratically the same code and just a few lines to add, then I would prefer unlimited. Thank you, Kat!

Comment: It's ready, but I don't want to delete what's here and there are a lot of changes. I think it might be better if you ask the question again and leave a link to that question here. That way the methods are available for others but separated (with separate behavior)

Comment: Alright, here it is --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72236135/make-a-radiobutton-list-for-the-stored-rpivottable-configuration-name
Thank you.