# Make a radiobutton list for the stored rpivottable configuration name

Tags: r, rpivottable

The following is a link to a code that allows you to make several configuration savings, which you can load anytime as long as you don't clear your cookies.
I would like to know if it's possible to make a radiobutton, that displays a list of all the stored names.

The link:
[Make several configuration saves/loadings of rpivottable on R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72208780/make-several-configuration-saves-loadings-of-rpivottable-on-r)

Comment: I forgot to mention that you won't see the radio buttons in the viewer pane; you have to open it up in your browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I've got:

- save with custom name
- retrieve by name
- retrieve by radio button
- delete by button

You may want to adjust the size or position of the radio button container. It depends on how you use it. Right now the container will continue to grow (up to a point) as you add more content.

This still uses the file or webpage name, so if you have more than one spreadsheet, you'll be able to save and keep the configurations separated.

The YAML, options, CSS, libraries, and sample data.

````
---
title: "testing rpivotTable cookie-ishness"
author: "me"
date: '2022-05-12'
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

<style>
body {    /*push content away from far right and left edges*/
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-left: 2%;
}
.main-container {
  max-width: unset;
}
.btn {    /*Added other buttons*/
  vertical-align: middle;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #000000;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #000000;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: .5px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.15em;            /*Changed from 1.3em*/
    padding: .3em 0px;
    width: 20em;                 /*Changed from 18em*/
    text-decoration: none; /*no underline!!*/
    cursor: pointer;
}
.btn:active { /*simulate movement; added other buttons*/
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}
</style>

```{r data,include=F}
# devtools::install_github("fraupflaume/rpivotTable")
library(rpivotTable)
library(tidyverse)
data(mtcars)

```
````

The buttons (not radio) and `rpivotTable`.

````
## Make it Interesting...or not

Do you want to save or restore the previously saved pivot tables' configuration?

<a id='saveNamed' class='btn' style="background-color:#003b70;color:white;">Save Configuration by Name</a>
<a id='restoNamed' class='btn' style="background-color:#b21e29;color:white;">Restore Configuration with Custom Name</a>
<a id='remoSaved' class='btn' style="background-color:black;color:white;">Remove Saved Configuration</a>


```{r showMe, echo=FALSE, fig.show="hold"}
rpivotTable(mtcars, rows="am", cols = c("cyl"), width = "90%", 
            height = "40%", subtotals = TRUE,
            rendererOptions = list(
              c3 = list(legend = list(show = FALSE), 
                        data = list(labels = TRUE),
                        options = list(responsive = TRUE,
                                       maintainAspectRatio = FALSE),
                        size = list(width = "600",
                                    height = "500")),
              d3 = list(size = list(width = "500", height = "500")) 
            ))
```
````

The remaining code is Javascript. This creates the events, saves, retrieves, and deletes configurations, and creates the radio buttons.

````
```{r listenOrElse,results="asis",engine="js"}

// for ONE TABLE
setTimeout(function(){  // add to buttons
  radioStar();  // <= added in v3
  document.querySelector('a#saveNamed').addEventListener('click', savoring); 
  document.querySelector('a#restoNamed').addEventListener('click', giveItBack);
  document.querySelector('a#remoSaved').addEventListener('click', remIt);  // removing configs
  function savoring() {                              // function to save
    el = document.querySelector('.rpivotTable');
    msg = "Choose a name for the configuration that you are saving.";
    inName = prompt(msg, ['Enter a name with no spaces or special characters'])
    if(inName === null) {return;};                   // they changed their mind; nothing saved
    inName = inName.replace(/[^a-z0-9.]/gi, '');     // validate string
    path = window.location.pathname.split("/").pop().split(".").slice()[0]; //filename
    elId = el.getAttribute("id");
    stringy = $('#' + elId).data("pivotUIOptions");  // collect rows/col filters
    delete stringy['aggregators'];                   // remove not-parse-friendly keys
    delete stringy['renderers'];
    stringy2 = JSON.stringify(stringy);              // one key:value pair for storage
    window.localStorage.setItem(path + '_' + inName, stringy2);  // STORE it!
    radBuilder(inName);  // <= added in v3; mod v4; add radio btn for new saved name
  };
  function giveItBack() {                           // function to regurgitate
    //el = document.querySelector('.rpivotTable');
    msg = "Enter the name of the configuration you would like to retrieve.";
    confName = prompt(msg, ["Enter a name with no spaces or special characters"]);
    if(confName === null) {return;}; 
    confName = confName.replace(/[^a-z0-9.]/gi, '');    // validate string
    retriever(confName);
  }
  function retriever(confName) {  // <= added in v3
    console.log("I'm listening! I swear!");
    el = document.querySelector('.rpivotTable');
    ods = [...el.ownerDocument.scripts];             // make it an array
    path = window.location.pathname.split("/").pop().split(".").slice()[0]; //filename
    elId = el.getAttribute("id");
    where = ods.filter(function(ods){             // filter scripts for data
      return ods.dataset['for'] === elId;
    })[0].innerHTML; 
    where2 = JSON.parse(where).x.data;            // format data for pivotUI()
    where3 = HTMLWidgets.dataframeToD3(where2);   // ...still formatting
    if(window.localStorage.getItem(path + '_' + confName) === null) { // alert
      len = window.localStorage.length
      var str;
      for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        w = window.localStorage.key(i);
        w2 = w.split("_").pop();   // remove file/page name <= changed in v3
        str = str + w2 + '\n';     // make one long string of names
      }
      str2 = "WARNING: There is no saved pivot table configuration with the name " + confName + '.';
      str2 += " Here is a list of the configuration names that are currently stored for this page:\n";
      str2 += str;
      alert(str2);  // next step is a change in v3
      giveItBack(); // when unmatched name is chosen instead of re-prompting send them back
    }
    gimme = window.localStorage.getItem(path + '_' + confName); // get storage
    gimmeMore = JSON.parse(gimme);                            // prepare for recall
    if(where.includes('"subtotals":true')){       // is the option 'subtotal' used?
      gimmeMore.renderers = $.pivotUtilities.subtotal_renderers;
      gimmeMore.dataClass = $.pivotUtilities.SubtotalPivotData;
    }; 
    if(where.includes('"tsv":true')){             // is the option 'tsv' used?
      gimmeMore.renderers = $.extend(gimmeMore.renderers, $.pivotUtilities.export_renderers);
    };
    if(where.includes('sortAs')){
      // passed as a function, they will get lost in save & retrieve
      stringy = $('#' + elId).data("pivotUIOptions").sorters;
      gimmeMore.sorters = stringy;
    };
    $('#' + elId).pivotUI(where3, gimmeMore, true, "en"); // put it back!
  }
  function remIt(){
    el = document.querySelector('.rpivotTable');
    msg = "Identify the configuration for removal.";
    remName = prompt(msg, ['Enter a name with no spaces or special characters'])
    if(remName === null) {return;};                   // they changed their mind; nothing saved
    remName = remName.replace(/[^a-z0-9.]/gi, '');     // validate string
    path = window.location.pathname.split("/").pop().split(".").slice()[0]; //filename
    window.localStorage.removeItem(path + '_' + remName);
    rgetter = document.querySelector('#' + remName).parentNode;
    rgetter.remove();
  }
  function radioStar() { // create container *once*; size may have to be adjusted
    if(document.querySelector('#radIsland') == null) { // if an alert doesn't exist
        // one time = create island for radio buttons
      contLabel = document.createElement('div');
      contLabel.setAttribute(
        'style',
        'font-size: 1.2em; font-face: bold; color: #003b70; display: flex; flex-flow: wrap row;');
      contLabel.textContent = 'Choose from the available check points:';
      configCont = document.createElement('div');
      configCont.id = 'radIsland';
      configCont.setAttribute(
        'style',
        'border: 1px solid #003b70; min-width: 11em; width: auto; max-width: 55em; min-height: 10em; height: auto; border-radius: .5em; color: #003b70; display: flex; flex-flow: wrap row;'
      );
      pEl = document.querySelector('.rpivotTable').parentNode;
      pEl.prepend(configCont);        // but box above rpivottable
      pEl.prepend(contLabel);         // put the label on top
    }
    radCreation();
  }
  function radCreation(){
  // if island exists then move on
  // create radio buttons; when savoring runs, radio buttons need to be rebuilt/validated?
    var wk, rB, rLab, desc, newL, rCont, path, len;
    path = window.location.pathname.split("/").pop().split(".").slice()[0]; //filename
    len = window.localStorage.length
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      wk = window.localStorage.key(i);
      ind = wk.lastIndexOf('_');
      wkFile = wk.substr(0, ind);   // remove file/page name and table number
      chName = wk.split("_").pop();      // user chosen name
      if(wkFile === path) {              // only show radio if file names match
        radBuilder(chName);
      }
    }
  }
  function radBuilder(chName){
    console.log('building a button');
    rB = document.createElement('input');
    rB.type = 'radio';
    rB.name = 'rBtn';       // only one radio w/ same name can be selected at once
    rB.id = chName;         // id's have to be unique for rad groups
    rB.value = chName;
    rB.setAttribute(
        'style',
        'margin: 2px;');
    rB.addEventListener('click', function(){
      retriever(this.value)
    });
    rLab = document.createElement('label');
    rLab.htmlFor = chName;
    desc = document.createTextNode(chName);
    rLab.appendChild(desc);
    newL = document.createElement('br');
    fItem = document.createElement('div');
    fItem.setAttribute(
      'style',
      'width: 10em; height: 1.1em; margin: auto;');
    fItem.appendChild(rB);
    fItem.appendChild(rLab);
    fItem.appendChild(newL);
    rCont = document.getElementById('radIsland');
    rCont.appendChild(fItem);
  }
}, 500);


```
````

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

#### If you remove a configuration, the radio button goes away, as well.

[image]
[image]

#### Saving a configuration will add a radio button for that configuration at that time

[image]
[image]

#### You can add as many configurations as you would like.

[image]

#### Just select a new radio to change to a different configuration.

[image]